# Evaluating expressions contained as strings

Tags: common-lisp

I've a database which returns vaild CL expressions within double quotes.

Is it possible to convert these strings to expressions.

For example, I make a query from this DB via CLSQL and as a result it returns me:

`"(foo a b)"`

How should I convert this expression to:

`(foo a b)`

and further evaluate it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
> (read-from-string "(foo a b)")
(FOO A B) ;
9
```

The `9` is the second of multiple values produced by `read-from-string`; you can ignore it:

```
(eval (read-from-string "(foo a b)"))
```

will do what you want given the proper definitions.

Comment: Thanks, how can i could not find that function?

Answer (score 4):

```
* (read-from-string "(+ 1 2)")

(+ 1 2)
7
```

There is a security problem. See the variable `*read-eval*`.

```
* (read-from-string "#.(+ 1 2)")

3
9
```

You really need to make sure that `*read-eval*` is `NIL`, so that reading will not evaluate code.

```
* (let ((*read-eval* nil)) (read-from-string "#.(+ 1 2)"))

debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR:
  can't read #. while *READ-EVAL* is NIL
```

Additionally calling `EVAL` on arbitrary input from a database is not a good idea.

Usually you want to make sure that the code does only call allowed functions.